# Store image with SQLite - Ionic 3.x

Tags: ionic-framework, sqlite, ionic3

I'm trying to save an image from the camera in SQLite, but when I display the image in an img tag, the image doesn't appear. Only the blank card is displayed. And I'd like not to save on photo library.

[HERE IS THE FULL SOURCE CODE](https://github.com/paulogusstavo/PhotoBoard)

**//The sql to create a table (SQLite)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fotos (id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, img TEXT, disciplina_id integer, FOREIGN KEY(disciplina_id) REFERENCES disciplinas(id))
```

**//Function to open camera.**

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  correctOrientation: true,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true
}

this.camera.getPicture(options)
  .then((imageData) => {
    let base64Image = null;

    base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

    //Salvar fotos no banco interno.
    this.addPhoto(base64Image);
    this.fotoProvider.insert(base64Image);

  }, (error) => {
    console.error(error)
    this.ionViewDidEnter();
  });
```

**//Insert the images in a array.**

```
public getPhotos(idDisciplina: number) {
return this.dbProvider.getDB()
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    let sql = 'SELECT img FROM fotos WHERE disciplina_id = ?';
    let data = [idDisciplina];

    return db.executeSql(sql, data)
      .then((data: any) => {
        if (data.rows.length > 0) {
          let fotos: any[] = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            var foto = data.rows.item(i);
            fotos.push(foto);
          }
          return fotos;
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => console.error(e));
  })
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

}

**//To show image**

```
   <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let photo of photos">
        <ion-card>
          <img [src]="photo" *ngIf="photo" />
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Comment: i think you need to convert your image to base64 string, there is one plugin called Base64 of cordova by that you have to encode your image